# Tamil is not showing in php

Tags: php

I am sending tamil text from a form to php script but php is not recognize that.

Html Code

```
<form action="insert_into_db.php" method="post">

 <textarea name="message" class="form-control message-box" rows="5" id="comment" placeholder="enter your message here"></textarea>

</form>
```

PHP code in `insert_into_db.php`

```
<?php
$message = $_POST['message'];
echo $message;
```

User Input :- `இந்த டெமோ செய்தி உள்ளது`

Output :- `à®‡à®¨à¯à®¤ à®Ÿà¯†à®®à¯‡à®¾ à®šà¯†à®¯à¯à®¤à®¿ à®‰à®³à¯à®³à®¤à¯`

expected output :- `இந்த டெமோ செய்தி உள்ளது`

Please help me Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` or just `<meta charset="utf-8" /> `

Comment: Not working bro :( Already given

Comment: Given in `insert_into_db.php` file or in HTML file?

Comment: Yes php itself returning the same output

Comment: Like i didn't inserted into table

Comment: what browser do u use?

Comment: chrome browser bro

Comment: your code works, http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/8zpb-b6ev - just the your browser character encoding to unicode

Comment: What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the browser encoding first .

1. Go right side menu and click the settings
2. Scroll down page and click Show advanced settings
3. Search under `Web content` label and click customize fonts button
4. At the bottom of the popup box ,in `Encoding` select UTF-8

Comment: Thank you david, This was really helpful :)

Comment: This is hardly a generally applicable solution for every website *visitor*...